# parse.com row updates javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have class and know row ID, try update this row how it's showed in this topic

https://parse.com/questions/updating-a-field-without-retrieving-the-object-first

```
    var Point = Parse.Object.extend("items");
    var point = new Point();
    point.id = "L8bc5utrVD";

    // Set a new value on quantity
    point.set("title", "new title");

    // Save
    point.save(null, {
      success: function(point) {
        // Saved successfully.
      },
      error: function(point, error) {
        // The save failed.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
        console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
      }
});
```

but get error 
 "Failed to create new object, with error code: **have this item**"

Answer (score 1):

When `point` is created with `new`, it is not yet in sync. Fetching the model before saving it will resolve the issue.

Using promises:

```
var Point = Parse.Object.extend("items");
var point = new Point();
point.id = "L8bc5utrVD";

point.fetch() // returns a promise
.then(function(){
    point.set("title", "new title");
    return point.save(); // returns a promise
})
.then(successCallback, failCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but problem was in Parse.Cloud.beforeSave function